# Seaborn jointplot hex option does not produce figure

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, seaborn

I am plotting a Pandas DataFrame as a Seaborn jointplot and would like to use the 'hex' function:

```
g = sns.jointplot("Xs", "Ys", data=PlotData, kind='hex', color="#4CB391")
```

The DataFrame is all floats and does not contain any NaNs:

```
In [34]:  PlotData.describe()
Out[34]: 
                 Xs            Ys
count  47856.000000  47856.000000
mean       2.125714     -0.458991
std        0.423019      1.750042
min        0.000000    -23.829382
25%        2.000000     -1.195314
50%        2.000000      0.000000
75%        2.301030      0.000000
max        5.939478     11.099151
```

The result is a blank figure, though it does produce the marginal distributions and the regression statistics:

[image]

What might I be missing?  I am using Python 3.4, Seaborn 0.7, and Pandas 0.18.  Thanks!

**UPDATE**  When making the change suggested by Peter below, here is the result:

[image]

So it appears that the concentrated points near x=2 are causing extreme scaling.

Comment: Thank you for the update. It's still not a typical hex-plot. Seems your data is not really fitted for that kind of plotting.

Comment: I agree.  The marginal distributions were a bit misleading in this regard, imho.  This is also why scatterplots, which allow overlapping points, are dangerous when you have 50k data points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like there is one pixel close to the mean (2, -0.5) that is colored. The standard deviation of your data set is also low, so perhaps the bins are too small and there are too many outliers to see the actual distribution. I would suggest either removing the outliers and trying again or explicitly setting the axis limits using [jointplot](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html).

Comment: Interesting. Now you say it, i actually see two green dots. One could try ```kind=kde``` and play with different values of the bandwith using ```bw=x``` to see if this binning/smoothing is the problem. Nonetheless, i expected one big hex, if data is that centered. Maybe looking up the sources is needed. But your recommendations sound very solid!

Comment: Yup, the issue is the data is crazy concentrated at very particular points, especially (2,0), which drowns out the rest and leads to tiny bins.  This shows it a bit better:  sns.jointplot("Xs", "Ys", data=PlotData, kind='hex', color="#4CB391", ylim=(-1.5,1.5), xlim=(1.9,2.3)).

Comment: Amazing eye, by the way

Comment: @crow_t_robot Just out of curiosity: could you add the new plot after the changes Peter recommended to your question (like an update; if it's not too much work)?